# Load Vue Component from ouside src directory

Tags: vuejs2

I have a project started with the vue-cli, and i'd love to include a component from a different local folder. I'm not that great at webpack config, so I'm not sure if it's just as simple as adding another path to some config setting. I've looked around in the docs, but everything I'm finding shows me the awesome auto scaffolding that vue init project gives us.

Any ideas?

Here's what the project structure looks like:

```
webroot/
  -wp-content/
  -wp-admin/
  -wp-includes/
  -other PHP classes/
  -static/
  -vue/
    -global-components/ (<- this is where i'd like to put some generic .vue components)
    -app1/ (<- this was created by vue-cli and is where i'd like to build a specific vue app for a specific wordpress page/post)
    -app2/ (<- this was created by vue-cli and is where i'd like to build a different app for a specific wordpress page/post)
```

So, you can see there's a bunch of things going on in this repo, and I'd like to be able to reference both the src folder inside app1 and app2, but also have each app reference the global-components folder. I'm not sure that the client would like to push their custom components up to npm, and I don't think they want to build out their own private npm source, so I was hoping for a way to build multiple vue.js applications without copying these components to each individual app.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What different folder? Is it inside your repository?

Comment: it is, but it's not inside the project folder. the project folder is not at the root of the git repo. it's a weird setup that includes various other build systems and scripts.

Comment: If your project has a custom structure that you've set up describing that structure could really help folks provide an answer. They can either tell you how to utilize files in the other folder or explain the downsides of your folder structure.

Comment: I just edited the question to show the basic layout of my idea. not sure if it is possible.